# How to set startdate for a week manually using vb

Tags: vb.net, date

I'm trying to set the start day of the week based on server value. Say in my server start day of week is 1 means, the list starts from Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3 ...Sunday = 7 as like I need a list values.
How to get this list like this? Any suggestions welcome.
Here I have tried it.

```
 For Each item In datesItem

            Dim i = CType(item.DayOfWeek, DaysOfWeek.DaysOfWeek)
            Dim exists = [Enum].IsDefined(GetType(DaysOfWeek.DaysOfWeek), i)
            If Not exists Then
                i = CType(CInt(item.DayOfWeek), DaysOfWeek.DaysOfWeek)
                'Here I'm get that Starting value which I intend to add to tuple.
            Else
                datesTuple.Add(New Tuple(Of Integer, DaysOfWeek.DaysOfWeek, Date)(CInt(i), i, item))
            End If
        Next
```

Actual Need Result:

Server start day of week: 1
Output:
Monday - 1
Tuesday - 2
Wednesday - 3
Thursday - 4
.
.
Sunday - 7

Comment: By "server", do you mean the machine on which the program is running?

Comment: I mean in Sql server...not based on program...

Comment: Do you mean, if the current first day of the week is Monday, you need to add `Items(0)` to `Items(6)` to the `List(Of Tuple)`, instead if the first day is Sunday, you need to add `Items(1)` to `Items(6)` and insert `Item(0)` at index `0` of the List? Couldn't you pick the Items based on the current day of the week instead?

Comment: @jimi, I can't get your point. If the start day of week from sql server is, 1 means I need Monday as 1, Tuesday as 2....Sunday as 7...i dont want 0..For this case how could i get this?

Comment: The enumeration of .Net collections start from index 0. I'm referring to the collection indexer. The content of a List is whatever you want it to be, not a real concern. Post an example of the results when the *Server*'s (the reference Culture) first day of the week is Sunday. Btw, your Types are all undefined.

Comment: @Jimi, could you please show me an example as I mentioned in above comment to achieve it.

Comment: @SPYder Are you aware of the [DateTime.DayOfWeek Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.7.2) and the [DateTimeFormatInfo.FirstDayOfWeek Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.firstdayofweek?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: You already have a description on how to procede in my first comment. You should post: 1) The `DateTime` object that contains the *Server*'s reference Date, 2) The definition of `datesItem`, 3) an example of what your `List(Of Tuple)` should be if the reference `[DateTime].FirstDayOfWeek` is Sunday.

Comment: Still I didn't get the required result. @jimi